# Overriding the base class value from the second child class

Tags: c#, oop

Is it possible to override the BaseFilter.Type value from the Filter2 class in the following example?

```
void Main()
{
    BaseFilter abc = new Filter2();
    Console.WriteLine(abc.Type);

    Filter1 d = new Filter2();
    Console.WriteLine(d.Type);

    Filter2 e = new Filter2();
    Console.WriteLine(e.Type);
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class BaseFilter
{
    public virtual string Type { get { return "ABC"; } }
}

public class Filter1 : BaseFilter
{
    public new virtual string Type  { get { return "DEF"; } }
}

public class Filter2 : Filter1
{
    public override string Type  { get { return "X"; } }
}
```

In the sense, from the above example, I would like to see, if "abc.Type" can return the value "X". However, I don't want to remove the "new" keyword from the Filter1 class.

So, here is the final expectation

1. Filter1 class should not override the value from the BaseFilter class.
2. However, the Filter2 class should override the values from the BaseFilter and also the Filter1.

Is it possible with OOPS languages?

Comment: Shadowing with the `new` keyword is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

In general, that is a bad idea. I am answering from the java perspective, where we dont have that nice idea of getters.

But the point is: polymorphism in good OO design is about **behaviour**, not about **fields**!

Meaning: you don't want that subclasses have to change the content of **parent** fields in order to do so something. You want things to be the other way round, as described by the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)!

Comment: Java, this is C#...? Your assertion that it's a bad idea I think still stands.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you want this behaviour. Could you explain?

I'm not sure, but as I read your question you are about to violate all that are good about OO and polymorphism :-).

Below however I suggest an approach using an interface for the BaseFilter.Type on Filter2, but it is not a good design and is just for 'fun':

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SO39543589
{

  public interface ISecondTyper
  {
    string Type { get; }
  }

  // Define other methods and classes here

  public class BaseFilter
  {
    public virtual string Type { get { return "ABC"; } }
  }

  public class Filter1 : BaseFilter
  {
    public new virtual string Type { get { return "DEF"; } }
  }

  public class Filter2 : Filter1, ISecondTyper
  {
    string ISecondTyper.Type
    {
      get
      {
        return (this as BaseFilter).Type;
      }
    }
    public override string Type { get { return "X"; } }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      BaseFilter abc = new Filter2();
      Console.WriteLine(abc.Type);

      Filter1 d = new Filter2();
      Console.WriteLine(d.Type);

      Filter2 e = new Filter2();
      Console.WriteLine(e.Type);

      ISecondTyper st = e;
      Console.WriteLine(st.Type);

      Console.WriteLine("END");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```